# Sigsegv Java Fatal Error when using libjvm.so

Tags: java, jvm

I am doing reboot tests on `Sles12sp2` using `STAF v3.4.24` and after some time I get this error:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f105e11e712, pid=6577, tid=0x00007f1027efe700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x63c712][thread 139707363079936 also had an error]
  IndexSet::alloc_block_containing(unsigned int)+0x42
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /root/core or core.6577
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /root/hs_err_pid6577.log

[error occurred during error reporting, id 0xb]
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

I have searched on Google and most of the links were about C library. Java version is `8u121`. No core dump was found at the location proposed.

Comment: Some updates of the problem:   also I tried to increase Java memory: -XXMaxPermGen=2048m but this parameter is ignored in Java 8 and this issue is still reproducible. I have tried also with -Xmx=1024m but the same result.

Comment: Could you please paste the complete hs_error file

Comment: I've uploaded the file. Please check the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzW1jWdmyXcTM0NTNnRQZGtuRnM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Fairoz did you take a look on the file uploaded on Google Drive?

Comment: Sorry i will check that now...

Answer (score 2):

From the logs you got crash in C2 compiler thread, during compilation of "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator::handleStartElement" it could be sereous compilation bug. Without proper reporducer it will be difficult to identify the root cause in compiler and fix as wee.

As a work around you should exclude this method from compilation using -XX:CompileCommand=exclude, com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator::handleStartElement check the proper usage of the -XX:CompileCommand=exclude command

Comment: What do you mean by " Without proper reporducer it will be difficult to identify the root cause in compiler and fix as wee." ?? What should I do to find the root cause of this crash?

Comment: Hi @andriana i work in Oracle in Java team. Issue you found is Java bug to fix that it will be difficult for us as the crash occuring during compilation of  "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator::handleStartElement" method which is not jdk source. You no need to find the root cause, if it is easily reproduce kindly share the steps to reproduce we will look for fix at our end.

Comment: What does the XX:CompileCommand=exclude exactly do? Can this option affect the generation of the XML files or the XML files in general? If yes, how? If no, why?

Comment: Please read this - https://uberdev.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/xxcompilecommandexclude-jvm-option/

Comment: I have done a reboot test with 7 hours with the JVM option that you gave and I got another crash. Please check https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzW1jWdmyXcTRFdQWkdfcUpaZFU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: And please also check the JVM log file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzW1jWdmyXcTM085cnhWM01MVzQ/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: Will it be possible for you to share the test case, that i can reproduce at my end? As you got another C2 crash at org.jdom2.Element::getChild.

Comment: I have made a reboot script and I am trying to reproduce the issue without any specific application from my company. Also would you be so kind to check the core dump found? Link for the core dump: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzW1jWdmyXcTR1Y1VFpVMTFfSnc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Core dump is from the same crash you have posted https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzW1jWdmyXcTM0NTNnRQZGtuRnM/view ?

Comment: can you please analyze the core dump? Meanwhile i am trying to reproduce the issue and give you the steps to follow.

Comment: I managed to reproduce the issue by following the below steps:

- install STAF 3.4.24 from https://sourceforge.net/projects/staf/files/staf/V3.4.24/ , choose STAF3424-setup-linux-amd64-NoJVM.bin
- follow steps by step instalaltion
- install staf in /usr/local/staf
- install java 8u111

Comment: - create folder /home/go2test
- copy scripts startstaf.sh and xstaf.sh in folder created above
- put in /etc/xdg/autostart the files reboottests.desktop and staf.desktop
- put the script reboot_test.sh in any folder you want e.g in /root
- run reboot_test.sh

The script will do 300 reboot cycles. In our case the issue has been reproduced after 83 cycles.

Comment: Thanks Adriana i will try to reproduce once i am done with my current assignment.

Comment: But I am not sure that this will help you, anyway I have uploaded all the files needed in Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzW1jWdmyXcTWGtPM21OcFZKVW8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Andriana, looks like it is taking more time than i expected, could you file an issue with Java i will look into it. http://bugreport.java.com/submit_start.do

Comment: Hi Andriana, i have created issue on your behalf - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8180406

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. Please be aware that you will need also the files from Google Drive to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi Andriana, we are unable to reproduce this issue at our end. As it has lot of dependencies and require multiple reboots. Will it be possible for you to reduce to smaller test case and share?

Comment: Hi Fairoz, could you please tell me what seems to be the problem? As I have reduced the test case to the minimum

Comment: Hello @Fairoz, could you please answer my question above?

Comment: Hi @Adriana, sorry i didn't saw your question, I am working on a remote machine where reboots are difficult, hence i won't be able to run the application completly, if you could make it simpler test case that will be greater help. In JDK9 there are are comple of issues fixed, it will be good you can check on that also.